# std::ostringstream::str() outputs a string with '\0'

Tags: c++

Here's a code snippet from [CppRestSDK How to POST multipart data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497375/cpprestsdk-how-to-post-multipart-data)

```
std::stringstream bodyContent;
std::ostringstream imgContent;

bodyContent << ... << imgContent.str();
```

imgContent is the binary file content in which there's inevitably a '\0'.

I checked std::ostringstream::str() first,

```
std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "abc\0""123";
    std::string s = oss.str();
    cout << s.length();//3
```

Yes, the string would be sliced by '\0'. So I guessed the file eventually uploaded would be sliced by the '\0'. And I also checked the file, there are a lot of '\0's.

[image]

But unexpectedly, the uploaded file was intact. I got into deep confustion.

Below is the code to copy file content into the stream.

```
std::ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open(imagePath, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
std::ostringstream imgContent;
std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inputFile),
      std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
      std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(imgContent));
```

Edit:
Thanks @user17732522's help, I made this code to force a '\0' into the stream.

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
void test()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "abc\0""123"s;
    std::string s = oss.str();
    cout << s.length() << endl; //7

    cout << (&s[0])[4] << endl;
    cout << (&s[0])[5] << endl;
    cout << (&s[0])[6] << endl;
}
```

Conclusion: str() can return a string with '\0's.

Comment: An `std::string` object can itself store the zero byte (which is what the null-terminator really is). It's when you use e.g. string literals (like `"abc\0123"`) or try to get an old C-style string (with e.g. `c_str()` or `data()`) that it's treated as a terminator.

Comment: `"abc\0""123"` is a c-string, so `std::cout` prints to first zero encountered (there is no other data about string size). `imgContent.str()` returns a `std::string` which has size information. Extra termination zero at the end is only to maintain compatibility with C-API, so `std::string::c_str()` can be used in C-API.

Comment: `string s{ "Hello" }; s.push_back(0); s.push_back(0); s.push_back(0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
oss << "abc\0""123";
```

There will be slicing up to the `\0` here, because the overload of `operator<<` for `std::ostream` which will be chosen here expects a `const char*` pointer to a null-terminated character string and will interpret it as such. There is no overload of `operator<<` for `std::ostream` taking a reference to a `const char` array. If there was, the function would be able to tell the full size of the literal and print it including the embedded null character.

---

```
bodyContent << ... << imgContent.str();
```

Here however `str()` returns a `std::string` which stores an explicit size and can hold null characters as part of its contents. There is an overload of `operator<<` for `std::ostream` which expects a `std::string` and will write its full contents, not interpreting the string contents as a null-terminated string.

---

A string literal can be forced into a `std::string` even if null characters are embedded e.g. with the help of the user-defined literal operator `operator""s` which produces a `std::string`:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

oss << "abc\0123"s;
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I need to find a way to force a '\0' into the stream.